# grunt-init not recognised / added to path (windows)

Tags: gruntjs

I'm on Windows and installed the new grunt using:
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install -g grunt-init

grunt-init is the issue here.

If I try to run "grunt-init" in the command console, it is not recognised. Also after restarting the PC it's a nogo.
I checked the environment settings and grunt-init is indeed not included. In fact, when checking the node_modules directory (in "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules") I see a directory "grunt-init", but there is no .cmd or other executable whatsoever.

Before I file a bug I wanted to ask here, because it seems that other Windows users have no issues with this..

Comment: It seems to be also on Mac. I already filed a bug: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init/issues/29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently version 0.1.0, the version that will be installed by a regular `npm install -g grunt-init` is not added to the PATH, because it has no `bin` directory. If you install the lates version (currently 0.2.0rc3) it should work as expected. Therefor run:

```
npm install -g grunt-init@0.2.0rc3
```

At least on Mac it works, but I think it works out on Windows too

Comment: I'm trying the 0.3.1 version, but the path hasn't been created?

Answer (score 0):

FIRST make sure that you do:

```
npm uninstall -g grunt-init
```

Double check the following folders to ensure that grunt-init is gone:

```
[%USERNAME%]\AppData\Roaming\npm
[%USERNAME%]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
[%USERNAME%]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

After this is done, then as @marcello mentioned you should install current version of grunt-init (as of this writing):

```
npm install -g grunt-init@0.2.0rc3
```